# i want to read the content of a text file into a list

Tags: php

What I am doing is getting the content of a file in a list then according to the content of txt file i have created 3 variables name phnno and dob the txt file looks like this

`talha,04236522155,22/10/1990 Roshan,04235290600,08/11/1999`

and my code looks like this

```
function read_file() {
    $file_name=$GLOBALS['file_name'];

    $target="uploads/".$file_name;

    $myfile = fopen("$target", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");

    while (!feof($myfile)) 
    {
        # code...
        $buffer=fgets($myfile,"4096");

        list($name,$cellphn,$dob)=explode(",",$buffer);

        $namearr=array($name);

        foreach ($namearr as $value) {
            # code...
            echo($value);
        }
    }
   fclose($myfile);
}
```

The output is talha Roshan which is right but now i want to display only 1st name how should i do that and what if i only want to read phone numbers from the file store it in an array or list and then insert them into database? so the crux is How should i access elements of my choice from this array? how should i insert all or selected names in databse? and how should i only ready phone numbers from the file

Comment: Why is this question tagged [tag:mysql]?  If you're trying to import a CSV into MySQL, have you considered [mysqlimport](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqlimport.html) or [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html)?  If it has nothing to do with MySQL and/or you *want* to parse the files into PHP data structures, have you considered [`fgetcsv()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)?

Comment: @eggyal i also want to read the contents of csv and excell files

Comment: To read Excel files, have you considered using a library like [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)?

Comment: no brother i am basically new to php i was asp.net and windows phone developer before now my company has entrusted me with the job of php development also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSV file(test.csv) data like:

```
talha,04236522155,22/10/1990 
Roshan,04235290600,08/11/1999

<?php $file = fopen("test.csv","r");
print_r(fgetcsv($file));fclose($file);?>

Output:
Array([0] => talha[1] => 04236522155[2] => 22/10/1990)
Array([0] => Roshan[1] => 04235290600[2] => 08/11/1999)
```

Now you can get any field value from from file through foreach loop.